# Serial Counter in digital electronics

Tags: digital-logic, serial, counter

What exactly is a serial counter in digital electronics?

Someone told me it is a way of to design a counter with shift registers and some combinational circuit to obtain s counter that operates serially .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is readily available.

Comment: @LeonHeller: Why not post a link for the OP to follow?  This almost sounds like the OP doesn't understand what he is asking - why not point him/her to an appropriate source of information?

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Digital_Circuits/Registers_and_Counters) may be what you are looking for. There are many ways to "count" using digital electronics: shift registers, barrel/cascade shifters, etc., and many more components and methodologies to achieve "counting." For shift register counters in particular, there are two types, [Ring and Johnson](http://www.ee.usyd.edu.au/tutorials/digital_tutorial/part2/register07.html).

"Serial" simply means "one, two, three..." etc. Counting may be binary instead of decimal (0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000...) Then a [74LS47](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5447a.pdf) or equivalent [binary-to-led](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_6.html) decoder can be used to display a decimal digit. Here is an [example](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-synccounter.html) if you can view it.

It's great to learn this old "combinational" style of digital electronic fundamentals, however it is (in my opinion) largely impractical to build a serial counter this way now. Today, all these functions and more can be achieved in a few lines of code on one tiny [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller). However, those are more advanced.